# convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss to dd mm yyyy, hh:mm am/pm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have got data as e.g. `2018-11-06T15:25:00` in the format. I want the output as `06 Jun 2018, 03:25 p.m.` Is there any way through which I can directly convert it?

Comment: Have you checked any docs., like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString ??

Comment: Have a look here (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @LGSon First of all solution that you have suggested is not what I have asked and please look at the format I have given ,  it does not have `z` in second

Comment: That dupe link holds all you need (2 pages of answers), you just need to read it, so with the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest using `momentjs`. Just use given format `DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm a`.

**Example code:**

```js
const date = '2018-11-06T15:25:00';

console.log(moment(date).format('DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm a'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @LGSon I didn't see your comment when I start adding my answer.

Comment: Well, I think that users not putting enough effort into their questions shouldn't get an answer, which were more why I commented about it. If the OP would have taken the time to read the docs. they would found their answer